# Texture artifacts and GLSL bump mapping

Tags: opengl, procedural-generation, normal-mapping

I'm working on a 3d terrain. I tried out some existing GLSL implementations for bump mapping using normal maps from [a Procedural Infinite 3D Cave Generation tutorial](http://jmonkeyengine.org/groups/user-code-projects/forum/topic/procedural-infinite-3d-cave-generation/).

The actual code that I used is in the [Cave3D repository](https://code.google.com/p/cave3d/), not the one in the post. Here's their [vertex shader](https://code.google.com/p/cave3d/source/browse/trunk/ardor3d/cave3d/shaders/triplanaltexturing.vert) and their [fragment shader](https://code.google.com/p/cave3d/source/browse/trunk/ardor3d/cave3d/shaders/triplanaltexturing.frac). The textures can be found on the same repository.

Note that this shader uses tri-planar texturing.

The problem is that I'm getting the following artifacts - black spots:

[image]

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Comment: From [a look at their sample images](https://code.google.com/p/cave3d/) it might just be by design, and those are little peaks you're seeing the (black) back of.